# Programmatically trigger admin save action on product

Tags: product, admin, ce-1.8.1.0, controllers

I have been troubleshooting a problem for hours. I can't explain why, but the problem is resolved when I go to the product in admin and click "Save" for that product (without changing anything). I am guessing this has something to do with the batch upload.

I have written a script that loops through all products and then calls save(), but this doesn't have the same effect as saving the product via the admin controller action (see `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController`). Here is my basic script, I change the short description just for testing the save success:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php

<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->load();
    echo 'Product: ' . $product->getId() . ' - ' . $product->getName() . "\xA";

    $product->setShortDescription('N/A');
    $product->save();
}
?>
```

Does anyone know how to programmatically trigger the admin save action? That is, I need to replicate clicking the 'Save' button for each simple product in the catalog.

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of actually trying to use the save action or simulate the request, I decided to look deeper into what the function does and figure out which piece I needed.

It turns out I needed to run the following on all of the affected products:

```
    if (Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));
    }
```

The products must have not been assigned correctly during my batch upload (using dataflow profiles). Here is the full script in case it is useful to anyone:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php

<?php

require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($products as $product) {
    if ($product->getModshopVisibility() && !$product->isConfigurable()) {
        echo 'Product: ' . $product->getId() . ' - ' . $product->getName() . "\xA";

        if (Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));
        }

        $product->save();
    }
    else echo 'Skip ' . $product->getId() . "\xA";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of you looking for a batch load process:
https://gist.github.com/tegansnyder/2de24f96ab463f074b23

Answer (score 0):

The script from mtaube will only work for configurable items, if you need bundled items you can use

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php


<?php

ini_set('memory_limit', '8192M');

require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($products as $product) {
if ($product->getModshopVisibility() && !$product->isBundle()) {
    echo 'Product: ' . $product->getId() . ' - ' . $product->getName() . "\xA";

    if (Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));
    }

    $product->save();
}
else echo 'Skip ' . $product->getId() . "\xA";
}

?>
```