# Product price attribute is not showing up on details page

Tags: product, attributes, price

The prices of my products are showing up in the grid results, but when I open them up as a detail page, there is no price. I found out when I save the product (without changing anything) it's fixing it.

I have done this already: [programmatically-trigger-admin-save-action-on-product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23648/programmatically-trigger-admin-save-action-on-product)

But it does not work this way. I have to explicitly save them via the admin panel. Has anyone a clue how I can fix this without saving all my products 1 by 1. I tried bulk saving them too via the admin panel, but it only works 1 by 1.

Thanks in advance.

ps: Database wise I [diffed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility) it with 2 sql files and saw some change and additions in a lot of tables. I need to trigger this programmatically, because creating a query takes ages (random id's for all kinds of stuff)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem. I used MAGMI to import all the products and I magically found out that the Minimum Manafacturer Retail Price (or something) was lower then the regular price so it wasn't shown (probably not set at all in database). It has to do with the attribute:

Apply MAP (if no, this option is turned off)

[image: Apply MAP]

No is selected but probably under water no is not selected :P So the best way to apply this to all the products is to select them all and edit the attributes, and assign Apply MAP to no.